# What's the default value of timeout for rtmpproto.c in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, flv, live-streaming

I made a rtmp streaming android app using ffmpeg. I want to know the timeout while streaming but network offline. I checked the [rtmpproto.c](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/rtmpproto_8c_source.html#l03098) implementation:

> {"timeout", "Maximum timeout (in seconds) to wait for incoming connections. -1 is infinite. Implies -rtmp_listen 1",  OFFSET(listen_timeout), AV_OPT_TYPE_INT, {.i64 = -1}, INT_MIN, INT_MAX, DEC, "rtmp_listen" },

I think the timeout option is what i want. But i didn't find the default value of it.

What's the default value of the **timeout** option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value `{.i64 = -1}` meaning infinite, according to the code you quoted.

Comment: How do you know `{.i64 = -1}` is the default value setting?

Comment: Because the other options are defined the same way. For eg. `rtmp_buffer` says `Set buffer time in milliseconds. The default is 3000` and the value is `{.i64 = 3000}`. Same logic should apply for `timeout`

Answer (score 0):

Load **rtmp** url in **ijkmediaplayer**, **ijkplayer** with
replace your all setOption with below setOption to easily load `rtmp://....`  url

```
        mMediaPlayer = new IjkMediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setOption(IjkMediaPlayer.OPT_CATEGORY_PLAYER, "FAST", 1);
        mMediaPlayer.setOption(IjkMediaPlayer.OPT_CATEGORY_FORMAT, "analyzeduration", 1L);
        mMediaPlayer.setOption(1, "analyzemaxduration", 100L);
        mMediaPlayer.setOption(1, "probesize", 100L);
        mMediaPlayer.setOption(1, "flush_packets", 0L);
        mMediaPlayer.setOption(4, "framedrop", 0L);
        mMediaPlayer.setOption(4, "packet -buffering", 0L);
        mMediaPlayer.setOption(IjkMediaPlayer.OPT_CATEGORY_FORMAT, "fflags", "nobuffer");
        mMediaPlayer.setOption(IjkMediaPlayer.OPT_CATEGORY_PLAYER, "mediacodec-HEVC", 1);
        mMediaPlayer.setOption(IjkMediaPlayer.OPT_CATEGORY_PLAYER, "mediacodec", 1);
        mMediaPlayer.setOption(IjkMediaPlayer.OPT_CATEGORY_PLAYER, "mediacodec-Auto-Rotate", 1);
        mMediaPlayer.setOption(IjkMediaPlayer.OPT_CATEGORY_PLAYER, "mediacodec-handle-Resolution-Change", 1);
        mMediaPlayer.setOption(IjkMediaPlayer.OPT_CATEGORY_PLAYER, "opensles", 0);
```